# How to Alpha matte an object with another?

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency, render-layers

Excuse me, I have two render layers, one for Suzan, the other is for a circle, and I want to set the circle to be the alpha matte for Suzan, like the image below:

[image]

I tried to do it, but the result was not that good, here is my nodes setup:

[image]

If there is a way to do it without separating each object in a render layer, this will be great.

Thanks every one :)

Stay safe :)

Comment: Use Crytpomattes watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBJQM-gIob8 and read: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/matte/cryptomatte.html

Comment: Thanks, @susu, I tried doing it with Cryptomatte, but I figured out that I can use it for hiding a part of an object, not showing it, which is my case. If you were able to do it with Cryptomatte, please let me know your setup. Thanks so much :)

Comment: If you found an answer please write it down on the answers section below, so that others with a similar question can learn from you.

Comment: All right, @susu, I will :)